# Should variables only used within a single method be declared within the class or the method?

Tags: java, class, variables, methods, instantiation

I am programming in Java. I know it probably doesn't matter much on modern, fast computers, but when you create an object from a class used multiple times, is it preferable to declare method-specific variables within the methods, where it will be declared every time the program is run, or within the class?

Comment: A variable is not instantiated. It's declared, and assigned, but not instantiated. Post code.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm guessing instantiate = initialize?

Comment: That's what I'm guessing to. But I'd prefer not having to guess, by seeing the code.

Comment: Ah, I used the wrong terminology. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Method-specific variables (variables which using is bounded by one method only) should be without any doubts declared within the method where they are used. It basically has nothing with the performance, but it's all about design, readability and OOP principles according to which you should not expose details of your implementation.

I suggest you show the code you are writing, otherwise trying to guess is error prone, and you are going to be hugely downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

If a separate copy of the variable is needed for each instance, then it should be an instance variable.  An example might be creating a separate copy of length and width variable within the Rectangle class.

If you are creating a variable that is not tied to an instance, it can be a local variable (method variable).  The swap method is a good example.  If you are swapping two indexes in an array a temporary variable can be created to hold the value of first index.